# Here Maps SDK control scroll sensitivity

Tags: android, ios, flutter, here-api

I'm using HERE Maps in my flutter application. When scrolling on the map, the camera speed is too sensitive.

How do I control this?

I checked Mapview's module especially the MapCamera class, and could not find any documentation on it.

Is it even possible to limit the speed?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, kinetic panning used to be very sensitive. According to the release notes, this was optimized with **release 4.4.3.0** - this release is available upon request, but the next bigger release on [developer.here.com](https://developer.here.com) should also include this fix.

On top, you can customize the pan behavior by disabling the default action for the related gesture: `_hereMapController.gestures.disableDefaultAction(GestureType.pan);`

When listening for this gesture event, you can move the map yourself in a loop until the animation slowly stops.